# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

En mi intento de hacer una red neuronal que nos distinga entre 10 deportes, me da el siguiente fallo al crear una secuencia en tensorflow para implantarle a las neuronas unas capas para el entrenamiento.

Os dejo por aquí las versiones, código y el error completo que me da:

**Versiones**

- Windows 10 Pro 64bits
- Anaconda-client: 1.7.2
- Anaconda-navigator: 1.9.12
- Anaconda-project: 0.8.3
- Jupyter: 1.0.0
  Jupyter-client: 5.3.4
  Jupyter-console: 6.1.0
  Jupyter-core: 4.6.1
  Jupyterlab: 1.2.6
  Jupyterlab-server: 1.0.6
  Tensorflow: 2.3.0
  Keras: 2.2.0
  Numpy: 1.18.1
  Matplotlib: 3.1.3

**Importaciones de librerias**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
import keras
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.models import Sequential,Input,Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU
```

**Código anterior al error**

```
dirname = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'sportimages')
imgpath = dirname + os.sep 

images = []
directories = []
dircount = []
prevRoot=''
cant=0

print("leyendo imagenes de ",imgpath)

for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(imgpath):
    for filename in filenames:
        if re.search("\.(jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|tiff)$", filename):
            cant=cant+1
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            image = plt.imread(filepath)
            images.append(image)
            b = "Leyendo..." + str(cant)
            print (b, end="\r")
            if prevRoot !=root:
                print(root, cant)
                prevRoot=root
                directories.append(root)
                dircount.append(cant)
                cant=0
dircount.append(cant)

dircount = dircount[1:]
dircount[0]=dircount[0]+1
print('Directorios leidos:',len(directories))
print("Imagenes en cada directorio", dircount)
print('suma Total de imagenes en subdirs:',sum(dircount))

labels=[]
indice=0
for cantidad in dircount:
    for i in range(cantidad):
        labels.append(indice)
    indice=indice+1
print("Cantidad etiquetas creadas: ",len(labels))

deportes=[]
indice=0
for directorio in directories:
    name = directorio.split(os.sep)
    print(indice , name[len(name)-1])
    deportes.append(name[len(name)-1])
    indice=indice+1

y = np.array(labels)
X = np.array(images, dtype=np.uint8) #convierto de lista a numpy

# Find the unique numbers from the train labels
classes = np.unique(y)
nClasses = len(classes)
print('Total number of outputs : ', nClasses)
print('Output classes : ', classes)

train_X,test_X,train_Y,test_Y = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2)
print('Training data shape : ', train_X.shape, train_Y.shape)
print('Testing data shape : ', test_X.shape, test_Y.shape)

train_X = train_X.astype('float32')
test_X = test_X.astype('float32')
train_X = train_X / 255.
test_X = test_X / 255.

# Change the labels from categorical to one-hot encoding
train_Y_one_hot = to_categorical(train_Y)
test_Y_one_hot = to_categorical(test_Y)

# Display the change for category label using one-hot encoding
print('Original label:', train_Y[0])
print('After conversion to one-hot:', train_Y_one_hot[0])

#Mezclar todo y crear los grupos de entrenamiento y testing
train_X,valid_X,train_label,valid_label = train_test_split(train_X, train_Y_one_hot, test_size=0.2, random_state=13)

print(train_X.shape,valid_X.shape,train_label.shape,valid_label.shape)

#declaramos variables con los parámetros de configuración de la red
INIT_LR = 1e-3 # Valor inicial de learning rate. El valor 1e-3 corresponde con 0.001
epochs = 6 # Cantidad de iteraciones completas al conjunto de imagenes de entrenamiento
batch_size = 64 # cantidad de imágenes que se toman a la vez en memoria
```

**Dejo aquí el trozo de código que me da el error:**

```
sport_model = Sequential()
sport_model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='linear',padding='same',input_shape=(21,28,3)))
sport_model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
sport_model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2),padding='same'))
sport_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
sport_model.add(Flatten())
sport_model.add(Dense(32, activation='linear'))
sport_model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
sport_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
sport_model.add(Dense(nClasses, activation='softmax'))
```

**Y aquí el error que me da**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-47ccb626b918> in <module>
----> 1 sport_model = Sequential()
      2 sport_model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='linear',padding='same',input_shape=(21,28,3)))
      3 sport_model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
      4 sport_model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2),padding='same'))
      5 sport_model.add(Dropout(0.5))

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\sequential.py in __init__(self, layers, name)
     85 
     86     def __init__(self, layers=None, name=None):
---> 87         super(Sequential, self).__init__(name=name)
     88 
     89         # Add to the model any layers passed to the constructor.

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name +
     90                               '` call to the Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     92         else:
     93             # Subclassed network
---> 94             self._init_subclassed_network(**kwargs)
     95 
     96     def _base_init(self, name=None):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py in _init_subclassed_network(self, name)
    299 
    300     def _init_subclassed_network(self, name=None):
--> 301         self._base_init(name=name)
    302         self._is_graph_network = False
    303         self._expects_training_arg = has_arg(self.call, 'training')

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py in _base_init(self, name)
    105         if not name:
    106             prefix = self.__class__.__name__.lower()
--> 107             name = prefix + '_' + str(K.get_uid(prefix))
    108         self.name = name
    109 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in get_uid(prefix)
     69     """
     70     global _GRAPH_UID_DICTS
---> 71     graph = tf.get_default_graph()
     72     if graph not in _GRAPH_UID_DICTS:
     73         _GRAPH_UID_DICTS[graph] = defaultdict(int)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema proviene de tus importaciones, estás mezclando `Tensorflow` y `Keras`. Utiliza simplemente la API de `Keras` mediante `Tensorflow`.

Lo que te ocurre es que cuando Tensorflow va a realizar el grafo, se da cuenta de que no puede hacerlo porque estás usando la API de `keras` directamente, en vez de usarla a través de `tensorflow`. Para solucionar el problema realiza las importaciones así:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization, LeakyReLU
```